# recorrer una lista en python

Tags: python, lista, ordenamiento

como puedo recorrer esta lista generada por numeros random y luego verificar si dos numeros seguidos son iguales. Aca hice un codigo, pero no me ha servido.

```
import random

numero = int(input("Ingrese numero de dados:"))
if numero <= 0:
    print("ERROR.")
else:
    dados1 = []

for i in range(1,numero+1):
    dados1.append(random.randrange(1,7))
for n in dados1:
    if n == n+1:
        print("Iguales")



print(f"Jugador 1:{dados1}")
```

Comment: Al iterar por el bucle, `n` es el valor de cada dado. Si una tirada salió por ejemplo 3, en esa iteración `n` será 3, y la comparación `n == n+1` está comparando 3 con 4, y obviamente siempre será falsa. Lo que quieres es iterar por los índices de la lista y comparar `dados[i]` con `dados[i+1]`. Cuidado que `i` no llegue al último índice pues en ese caso no habrá elemento `i+1`.

Answer (score 1):

En realidad, casi lo tienes:

```
import random

numero = int(input("Ingrese numero de dados:"))
if numero <= 0:
    print("ERROR.")
else:
    dados1 = []

for i in range(1, numero + 1):
    dados1.append(random.randrange(1, 7))
for n in range(len(dados1) - 1):
    if dados1[n] == dados1[n + 1]:
        print("Iguales")

print(f"Jugador 1:{dados1}")
```

Ahora, vamos a analizar tu código y que falla:

asumamos que has ejecutado el código con 8 dados, 
resultado Jugador 1:[2, 1, 3, 3, 2, 2, 6, 2]

Ahora el código que comprueba la serie

```
for n in dados1:
    if n == n+1:
        print("Iguales")
```

Iteración 1 -> n = 2, n+1 = 3 por tanto 2 y 3 NO son iguales

se pretendía comparar 2 con 1 que son DISTINTOS

Iteración 2 -> n = 1, n+1 = 2 por tanto 1 y 2 NO son iguales

se pretendía comparar 1 con 3 que son DISTINTOS

Iteración 3 -> n = 3, n+1 = 4 por tanto 3 y 4 NO son iguales

se pretendía comparar 3 con 3 que son IGUALES

Iteración 4 -> n = 3, n+1 = 4 por tanto 3 y 4 NO son iguales

se pretendía comparar 3 con 2 que son DISTINTOS

Iteración 5 -> n = 2, n+1 = 3 por tanto 2 y 3 NO son iguales

se pretendía comparar 2 con 2 que son IGUALES

Iteración 6 -> n = 2, n+1 = 3 por tanto 2 y 3 NO son iguales

se pretendía comparar 2 con 6 que son DISTINTOS

Iteración 7 -> n = 6, n+1 = 7 por tanto 6 y 7 NO son iguales

se pretendía comparar 6 con 2 que son DISTINTOS

Te pongo para que puedas ver lo que pasa el código con el que he generado el texto anterior:

import random

```
numero = int(input("Ingrese numero de dados:"))
if numero <= 0:
    print("ERROR.")
else:
    dados1 = []

for i in range(1, numero + 1):
    dados1.append(random.randrange(1, 7))
# for n in range(len(dados1) - 1):
#     if dados1[n] == dados1[n + 1]:
#         print("Iguales")
#
print(f"Jugador 1:{dados1}")
vuelta = 0
for n in dados1:
    valor = dados1[vuelta] # tomo el valor actual de la serie
    vuelta += 1 # paso al siguiente número que será el mismo que en la siguiente vuelta
    if vuelta == len(dados1): # Si hemos alcanzado el final de la serie, salimos del bucle
        break
    valor2 = dados1[vuelta] # el valor del dado siguiente
    text = 'DISTINTOS'
    if valor == valor2: # comparamos ambos valores
        text = 'IGUALES'
    # imprimimos resultados
    print(f"Iteración {vuelta} -> n = {n}, n+1 = {n+1} por tanto {n} y {n+1} NO son iguales ")
    print(f"Se pretendía comparar {valor} con {valor2} que son {text}\n")
```

Answer (score 0):

Como ya se ha comentado, cuando iteras con un `for - in` sobre un iterable, el ciclo va obteniendo a través de la variable asociada un referencia a cada item del iterable. Es decir, en tu caso, `n` será cada entero almacenado en la lista, por lo que `n + 1` simplemente suma uno al item, no obtiene el item que le sucede en la lista. La opción obvia es usar `range` e indizar, pero normalmente es más lento que iterar con un `for`.

Una forma más eficiente que usar  `range` + indizado para ir comparando un elemento con el siguiente en un iterable cualquiera es usar un iterador:

```
dados = [4, 2, 6, 6, 3, 2, 2, 2, 5, 3, 3, 4]

dados_iter = iter(dados)
last = next(dados_iter) # primer item de la lista
for i, new in enumerate(dados_iter):
    if last == new:
        print(f"Encontrados dos {new} consecutivos en posición {i} y {i + 1}") 
    last = new
```

> Encontrados dos 6 consecutivos en posición 2 y 3
>   Encontrados dos 2 consecutivos en posición 5 y 6
>   Encontrados dos 2 consecutivos en posición 6 y 7
>   Encontrados dos 3 consecutivos en posición 9 y 10

Si no necesitas conocer los índices dónde se producen las repeticiones, puedes hacer simplemente:

```
dados_iter = iter(dados)
last = next(dados_iter) # primer item de la lista
for new in dados_iter:
    if last == new:
        print(f"Encontrados dos {new} consecutivos") 
    last = new
```

Hay que tener en cuenta que si aplicamos lo anterior sobre una lista vacía tendremos una excepción, pero es algo que podemos solucionar con un simple condicional por ejemplo:

```
if dados:
    dados_iter = iter(dados)
    ...
```

o manejando la excepción:

```
dados_iter = iter(dados)
try:
    last = next(dados_iter) # primer item de la lista
except StopIteration:
    print("Iterable vacío")
else:
    for i, new in enumerate(dados_iter):
        if last == new:
            print(f"Encontrados dos {new} consecutivos en posición {i} y {i + 1}") 
        last = new
```

ejemplo de comparación de tiempos de ejecución para lista de 10000 elementos:

```
%%timeit
for i in range(len(dados) - 1):
    if dados[i] == dados[i + 1]:
        pass
```

> 1.39 ms ± 29.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

```
%%timeit
dados_iter = iter(dados)
last = next(dados_iter)
for i, new in enumerate(dados_iter):
    if last == new:
        pass
    last = new
```

> 625 µs ± 8.12 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops
>   each)